# How to start a fragment from an activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run a class extending a fragment from a class extending AppCompactActivity, I have tried everything I have saw in Stackover flow and I cant get any to fix my problem. LineDetails is extending the Fragment

```
    Progress1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Fragment fr = new LineDetails();
            android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

XML

`<fragment android:name="com.almac.tracker.LineDetails"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

PART OF XML FOR ACTIVITY CLASS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:overScrollMode="never"
   android:scrollbars="none"
   tools:context=".Dashboard">
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place">
  </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 2):

If your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, then you cannot use `getFragmentManager()`.

In fact you should get rid of classes in the package `android.app` such as `android.app.FragmentManager`. You should use the support classes from the package `android.support.v4.app` such as `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

The stack trace reports that you don't have any Layout with id `R.id.fragment_place` inside your activity. Check the xml of your activity and correct the id of fragment holder.

Comment: thank you Nabin, I changed the code to your option and it runs with no error but the extended fragment page doesn't show us... it just crashes

Comment: Edit your question, and post the stack trace.

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: should the fragment_place be in the xml of the activity or the fragment

Comment: In the activity. Use a layout such as `FrameLayout` without any children.

Comment: could you take a look at my xml provided above - only a snipped of the xml

Comment: It looks okay, are you still getting the same error?

Comment: yea the fragment and activity are displaying over each other on the same screen

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: both pages are coming up one on top of another instead of on a separate screen

Comment: You should create a new activity with fragment and start that new activity for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing instead of adding without a refresh, just do an add. I also simplified one of your useless variables and just went straight to `ft` instead of having an intermediate `fm`.

```
Progress1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Fragment fr = new LineDetails();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your layout xml, It should have a **FrameLayout** with attribute `@+id/fragment_place` act as a placeholder for your **LineDetails** fragment.

If you already place `<fragment />` in your layout, you don't need to replace() it programmatically.

Comment: I have added my xml above

Comment: @Fionnuala If you already place `<fragment />` in your layout, you don't need to replace() it programmatically.

Comment: so the fragment is showing up, but over the top of the activity...both pages are showing on top of each other. I tried replacing 'ft.add' to 'ft.replace' but it still shows ontop

Comment: @Fionnuala Please provide some screenshot in these cases

Comment: screenshot provided

Comment: I think there some problem with the arrangement of your layout xml file. Do you use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as root?

Comment: FrameLayout is the root

Comment: when you use FrameLayout as root, everything is show up overlap on each other. Try to arrange your layout's elements using Relative/LinearLayout

Comment: so the FrameLayout should be inside say the RelativeLayout?

Comment: the <fragment /> should not be inside a same FrameLayout with other Views

Comment: I have added my full xml file, if you could tell me where I am going wrong that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Fionnuala I can't see the full xml in your question? Did you update it yet?

Comment: its uploaded now

Answer (score 0):

**getSupportFragmentManager()** should be used if activity extends **AppcompatActivity**

EDIT :
As per the Errors ! There is no View named **fragment_place** in the activity's layout that is @+id/fragment_place must exist in activity_main (If this is the layout attached to activity)